# I am so confused with uploading files in PHP

Tags: php, forms, upload, input

I have tried reading multiple tutorials, the PHP documentation and have no idea what I am doing.

Here is my form

```
<form action="beta_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20971520" /><!-- 20 Meg -->
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Now when I send that through here:

```
<?php 
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);

$username = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $username);
$password = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $password);
$name = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $name);
$email = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $email);

$upload_dir = '/beta_images/';

print_r($_FILES);

foreach ($_FILES['files']['error'] as $key => $error) {

    if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $check_name = $_FILES['files']['name'];

    $filetype = checkfiletype($check_name, 'jpg,jpeg');

        $temp_name = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $image_name = 'image_' . $name . '1';
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_dir . $image_name); 

    }

}
```

It brings back

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /blabla on line 18
```

I don't understand foreachs all too well, and when I `print_r` the array it dosen't help me one bit.

Would someone be so kind to help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: `$_FILES['files']` needs to be `$_FILES['file']`

Comment: @pekka yep - or `<input type="file" name="file[]" />` needs to be `<input type="file" name="files[]" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better follow this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

```
foreach ($_FILES['file'] as $file) {

    if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $check_name = $file['name'];

        // I assume you have to use the file type here, not name
        $filetype = checkfiletype($file['type'], 'jpg,jpeg');

        $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $image_name = 'image_' . $file['name'] . '1';
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_dir . $image_name); 

    }

}
```

Your files are in $_FILES['files'] so using foreach you have to go over each element/file and take its data.